# struts2 can't find action by wildcard when package extends from "json-default"

Tags: java, struts2

I want struts actions to return JSON type of results, so I extend the package from "json-default", and specifically, I use wildcard to map actions.

Struts works fine with wildcard when package extends from "struts-default".

However, struts can't find actions by wildcard when package extends from "json-default", it reports:

```
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/ajax] and action name [query] associated with context path [/myapp].
```

Below is part of my struts.xml:

```
<package name="ajax" namespace="/ajax" extends="json-default">
    <action name="*" class="action.modifyAction" method="{1}">
        <result type="json" name="success">
            <param name="includeProperties">success</param>
        </result>
        <result type="json" name="error">
            <param name="includeProperties">success,errorMsg</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Does package "json-default" not support wildcard, or do I have to add more configurations on my struts.xml?

I'm using struts-core-2.5.13 and struts-json-plugin-2.5.13.

Comment: not sure but maybe try both - extends="struts-default,json-default">

Comment: Single `*` is a special catch all mapping. Read about `Wildcard Default` in [Action Configuration](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html#action-default).

Comment: @isaace `json-default` extends `struts-default` no need to put both.